Element is working fine in Tailwind Play but not in the actual page
I'm trying to create a reusable components for a button that may have an icon and label. I'm using React+Next and Tailwind for my project. The default / idle state is correct, but the hover state is not. When I hovered my mouse on top of it, it only changed the button's bg color, not the icon and label. However, when I tried it in Tailwind Play, it worked just fine.
This is the class for the general button:
button-schemes.tsx:
'use client'
export type HexColor = `#${string}`;

export enum ButtonType {
    PRIMARY,
    SECONDARY,
    PRIMARY_ICON,
}

export enum ButtonWidth {
    FIT = 'w-fit',
    REG = 'w-[115px]'
}

export enum ButtonHeight {
    FIT = 'h-fit',
    MINI = 'h-[20px]',
    REG = 'h-[40px]'
}

export enum FontSize {
    SMALL = 'text-sm',
    BASE = 'text-base'
}

export interface ButtonColors {
    bgColorIdle: HexColor
    bgColorHover: HexColor
    bgColorDisable: HexColor
    labelColorIdle: HexColor
    labelColorHover: HexColor
    labelColorDisable: HexColor
}

export interface ButtonSizes {
    width: ButtonWidth
    height: ButtonHeight
    fontSize: FontSize
}

export const buttonSizeSchemes: { [type: string]: ButtonSizes; } = {
    [ButtonType.PRIMARY]: {
        width: ButtonWidth.REG,
        height: ButtonHeight.REG,
        fontSize: FontSize.BASE
    },
    [ButtonType.SECONDARY]: {
        width: ButtonWidth.REG,
        height: ButtonHeight.REG,
        fontSize: FontSize.BASE
    },
    [ButtonType.PRIMARY_ICON]: {
        width: ButtonWidth.FIT,
        height: ButtonHeight.REG,
        fontSize: FontSize.BASE
    },
}

export const buttonColorSchemes: { [type: string]: ButtonColors; } = {
    [ButtonType.PRIMARY]: {
        bgColorIdle: '#FA8A0A',
        bgColorHover: '#E37900',
        bgColorDisable: '#EEF0F3',
        labelColorIdle: '#FFFFFF',
        labelColorHover: '#FFFFFF',
        labelColorDisable: '#CDD2DB'
    },
    [ButtonType.SECONDARY]: {
        bgColorIdle: '#F3F6F9',
        bgColorHover: '#DDE1E7',
        bgColorDisable: '#EEF0F3',
        labelColorIdle: '#333333',
        labelColorHover: '#333333',
        labelColorDisable: '#CDD2DB'
    },
    [ButtonType.PRIMARY_ICON]: {
        bgColorIdle: '#F3F6F9',
        bgColorHover: '#576887',
        bgColorDisable: '#EEF0F3',
        labelColorIdle: '#576887',
        labelColorHover: '#FFFFFF',
        labelColorDisable: '#CDD2DB'
    },
}

button-general.tsx:
'use client'
import React, { SVGProps } from "react"
import { ButtonType, ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight, ButtonColors, buttonColorSchemes, buttonSizeSchemes } from "./button-schemes"

export interface ButtonGeneralProperties {
    type: ButtonType
    title?: string
    icon?: any
    onClick?: () => void
    disableWhen?: () => boolean
}

export const ButtonGeneral = (props: ButtonGeneralProperties) => {
    const { type, title, icon, onClick, disableWhen } = props

    const { bgColorIdle, bgColorHover, bgColorDisable, labelColorIdle, labelColorHover, labelColorDisable } = buttonColorSchemes[type]
    const { width, height, fontSize } = buttonSizeSchemes[type]

    return (
        <button
            className={`group ${width ? width : 'w-fit'} ${height ? height : 'h-fit'} p-[15px] bg-[${bgColorIdle}] hover:bg-[${bgColorHover}] disabled:bg-[${bgColorDisable}] rounded-3xl justify-center items-center gap-2.5 flex`}
            onClick={onClick}
            disabled={disableWhen && disableWhen()}
        >
            {icon ? icon : ''}
            <div className={`text-[${labelColorIdle}] group-hover:text-[${labelColorHover}] disabled:text-[${labelColorDisable}] ${fontSize} font-semibold leading-none tracking-wide`}>
                {title}
            </div>
        </button>
    )
}

icon-schemes.tsx:
import { HexColor } from "../buttons/button-schemes";

export enum IconType {
    PRIMARY,
    SECONDARY,
    TERTIARY,
}

export interface IconColors {
    fillColor: HexColor
    hoverColor: HexColor
}

export interface SvgIconProperties {
    name: string;
    type: IconType;
    size?: string | number;
}

export const iconColorSchemes: { [type: string]: IconColors; } = {
    [IconType.PRIMARY]: {
        fillColor: '#576887',
        hoverColor: '#F89D1D'
    },
}

edit-icon.tsx:
import { SvgIconProperties, iconColorSchemes } from "./icon-schemes";

const EditIcon = (props: SvgIconProperties) => {
    const { name, type, size } = props
    const colors = iconColorSchemes[type]

    return (
        <svg
            width={size ?? '18'}
            height={size ?? '18'}
            viewBox={`0 0 ${size} ${size}`}
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
            <path
                className={`fill-[${colors.fillColor}] group-hover:fill-[${colors.hoverColor}]`}
                d="M16 0C16.5304 0 17.0391 0.210714 17.4142 0.585786C17.7893 0.960859 18 1.46957 18 2V16C18 17.11 17.1 18 16 18H2C1.46957 18 0.960859 17.7893 0.585786 17.4142C0.210714 17.0391 0 16.5304 0 16V2C0 1.46957 0.210714 0.960859 0.585786 0.585786C0.960859 0.210714 1.46957 0 2 0H16ZM13.7 6.35C13.92 6.14 13.92 5.79 13.7 5.58L12.42 4.3C12.21 4.08 11.86 4.08 11.65 4.3L10.65 5.3L12.7 7.35L13.7 6.35ZM4 11.94V14H6.06L12.12 7.94L10.06 5.88L4 11.94Z"
            />
        </svg>
    )
}

export default EditIcon

this is how I use it:
            <ButtonGeneral
                type={ButtonType.PRIMARY_ICON}
                title='Edit User'
                icon={<EditIcon
                  name='Edit'
                  type={IconType.PRIMARY}
                  size='18'
                />}
                onClick={() =>
                  router.push(
                    `/admin-center/user-management/${userDetail?.user_id}/edit`
                  )
                }
              />

and this is the inspected element in the browser which worked flawlessly in Tailwind Play:
<button class="group flex h-[40px] w-fit items-center justify-center gap-2.5 rounded-3xl bg-[#F3F6F9] p-[15px] hover:bg-[#576887] disabled:bg-[#EEF0F3]">
  <svg width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path class="fill-[#576887] group-hover:fill-[#F89D1D]" d="M16 0C16.5304 0 17.0391 0.210714 17.4142 0.585786C17.7893 0.960859 18 1.46957 18 2V16C18 17.11 17.1 18 16 18H2C1.46957 18 0.960859 17.7893 0.585786 17.4142C0.210714 17.0391 0 16.5304 0 16V2C0 1.46957 0.210714 0.960859 0.585786 0.585786C0.960859 0.210714 1.46957 0 2 0H16ZM13.7 6.35C13.92 6.14 13.92 5.79 13.7 5.58L12.42 4.3C12.21 4.08 11.86 4.08 11.65 4.3L10.65 5.3L12.7 7.35L13.7 6.35ZM4 11.94V14H6.06L12.12 7.94L10.06 5.88L4 11.94Z"></path>
  </svg>
  <div class="text-base font-semibold leading-none tracking-wide text-[#576887] disabled:text-[#CDD2DB] group-hover:text-[#FFFFFF]">
    Edit User
  </div>
</button>

Can anybody help me? Thank you.
EDIT: Forgot to mention this. When I use ButtonType.PRIMARY and ButtonType.SECONDARY without any icon, it worked fine.

As per the documentation:

The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings in your source files.
If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
Don’t construct class names dynamically
<div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>

In the example above, the strings text-red-600 and text-green-600 do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
Always use complete class names
<div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>


You could:

Have the entire class in the variables you pass to className like
export const buttonColorSchemes: { [type: string]: ButtonColors; } = {
  [ButtonType.PRIMARY]: {
    bgColorIdle: 'bg-[#FA8A0A]',
    bgColorHover: 'hover:bg-[#E37900]',
    bgColorDisable: 'disabled:bg-[#EEF0F3]',
    labelColorIdle: 'text-[#FFFFFF]',
    labelColorHover: 'group-hover:text-[#FFFFFF]',
    labelColorDisable: 'disabled:text-[#CDD2DB]'

<button
  className={`… ${bgColorIdle} ${bgColorHover} ${bgColorDisable} …`}
  …
>
  {icon ? icon : ''}
  <div className={`${labelColorIdle} ${labelColorHover} ${labelColorDisable} …`}>
    {title}

export const iconColorSchemes: { [type: string]: IconColors; } = {
  [IconType.PRIMARY]: {
    fillColor: 'fill-[#576887]',
    hoverColor: 'group-hover:fill-[#F89D1D]'
  },
}

<path
  className={`${colors.fillColor} ${colors.hoverColor} …`}

Ensure button-general.tsx and button-schemes.tsx are covered by the content file globs.
Use the style attribute:
<button
  className={`… bg-[--idle] hover:bg-[--hover] disabled:bg-[--disable] …`}
  style={{
    '--idle': bgColorIdle,
    '--hover': bgColorHover,
    '--disable': bgColorDisable,
  }}
  …
>
  {icon ? icon : ''}
  <div
    className={`text-[--idle] group-hover:text-[--hover] disabled:text-[--disable] …`}
    style={{
      '--idle': labelColorIdle,
      '--hover': labelColorHover,
      '--disable': labelColorDisable,
    }}
  >
    {title}

<path
  className="fill-[--fill] group-hover:fill-[--hover] …"
  style={{
    '--fill': colors.fillColor,
    '--hover': colors.hoverColor,
  }}


safelist the classes, if you have a limited number of known colors:
module.exports = {
  safelist: [
    'bg-[#F3F6F9]',
    'hover:bg-[#576887]',
    'disabled:bg-[#EEF0F3]',
    // …
  ],
  // …
];



